# How to avoid GZip compressed assets getting modified every time running rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, asset-pipeline

We are using Rails' asset pipeline feature in v3.2. We are pre-compiling all assets locally and committing the pre-compiled assets into our Git repository. Every time we run `rake assets:precompile` all the GZip compressed versions of the generated assets in `public/assets/` are marked as modified. I suspect this is because the [GZip file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format) contains a header which includes a version number and a timestamp.

What's the best way to avoid this issue?

We have considered:

1. Using the [turbo-sprockets gem](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) to compile only assets that have changed. This seems the best option so far.
2. Precompiling on the target servers instead of locally. Makes deployments take significantly longer, esp. with frequent deployments and infrequently changing assets.
3. Not precompiling the GZip compressed assets and instead having the web server compress the static assets on the fly. Adds extra load on the web server and also Sprockets is supposed to use a higher compression factor than the web server leading to longer downloads.

Any other options?